# Can anybody tell me why my case statement below doesnt work for the negative values please?

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub tebakangkadi_c4()
    Dim value As Integer
    Dim result As String
    Dim gp As String
    Dim np As String

    value = Range("c4").value
    gp = IIf(nilai Mod 2 = 0, "Genap", "Ganjil")

    Select Case nilai
    Case 0 To 20
        result = "A"
    Case 21 To 50
        result = "B"
    Case 51 To 125
        result = "C"
    Case 126 To 1000
        result = "D"
    Case Is > 1000
        result = "E"
    Case -1 To -20
        result = "A"
    Case -21 To -50
        result = "B"
    Case -51 To -125
        result = "C"
    Case -126 To -1000
        result = "D"
    Case Is < -1000
        result = "E"
    End Select
    If value < 0 Then
        np = "Negative"
    Else: np = "Positive"
    End If
    Range("c5").value = "Category :" & result & " " & gp & " " & np
End Sub
```

Comment: From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/select-case-statement): The To keyword specifies a range of values. If you use the To keyword, the smaller value must appear before To.

Comment: ^^^^ `Case -20 To -1` etc.

Comment: i changed it , but the result keep showing "A" is there anything wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [`Select Case`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/select-case-statement) docs:

> The **To** keyword specifies a range of values. If you use the **To** keyword, the smaller value must appear before **To**.

Flip the numbers in your negative `Case`s.

```
Case -20 To -1
Case -50 To -21
etc.
```

Comment: i changed it from smaller to greater, but the result keep showing "A" to all value not just in range 0 to 20 or -20 to -1